# Possible to cache elements with jquery to improve show/hide time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a slide show that uses easing to hide/show divs.

A couple of the divs have flash videos and they are reloaded (that is, the file not the movie) every time the respective slide "shows".

Is it possible to cache these files so they dont have to be reloaded every time?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I'm using the Jquery plugin Cycle

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout:5000,
    cleartype: 0 
});
```

Comment: Could you show some of your code? Hiding/showing divs shouldn't necessarily cause it's content to reload.

Comment: Do you know if the videos are streaming or progressive downloads?  I second Colin's request for code.  Seeing as you're new to SO, you might find posting code on a site like jsfiddle.net to be easier than posting in SO's text editor.

Comment: @chprpipr the content is being downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Just doing some quick tests, in FF 4 (on a Mac), it looks like display none -> display block has a little lag, whereas visibility hidden -> visibility visible doesn't.
You could try reworking your slideshow script to toggle `visibility` rather than `display`